# How to make an Iterator that can Iterate many types of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, iterator

I'm trying to make an Iterator Class that can iterate a plentitude of objects of my choice. I've seen suggestions at college about using the type Object (since it's the object superclass) but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have made a constructor that receives as parameters Object[] and the number of elements. However, when I need to return that object it does not allow me saying its an incompatible type.

```
public class IteratorClass implements Iterator {
   Object[] objIt;
   int elemCounter;
   int currNumber = 0;
   /**
   * Constructor of the Iterador
   */
    public IteratorClass(Object[] objIt, int elemCounter) {
        this.elemCounter = elemCounter;
        this.objIt = objIt;

    }
    public Object next() {
         return objIt[currNumber++];
    }
```

}

I was expecting it to return the object of type I put in the constructor, but it's not allowing me to.

Comment: Start using java 1.5 and above, it has generics. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Note that Java 1.5 is now 15 years old.

Comment: Also, note that `Arrays.asList(yourArray).iterator()` would give you a correctly-functioning iterator in much less code.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I think this is supposed to be a learning exercise, so the task **is** to try and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @TiagoMirais, please explain what does this mean: "it does not allow me saying its an incompatible type". Where are you getting this error? Does your `IteratorClass` not compile, or the code where you are trying to use its `next()` function?

Comment: This is in fact a learning exercise from college so I must use an iterator class

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The error I was getting was from the interface I'm using. It appears I forgot to change the object return type from the interface that this class implements. However, thank you for your time!

Comment: Okay, write your own iterator if you need to, but you still need to use generics - in fact, I assume that's the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work was that the interface I'm implementing in this class has the method next() returning an object of a type different from Object.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (a checkmark on the left), so that this question does not appear in lists of unanswered questions.